# Bind images to a ListView in metro app (win 8 app)

Tags: c#, image, listview, microsoft-metro, bind

I have a list of images and I need to bind the images to the image controller that is inside a listview.

My Xaml Code

```
<ListView Name="lbxItems" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged_1" ItemsSource="{Binding Srcimg}">
                                <StackPanel>
                            <Image Name="item" Height="113" Source="{Binding}" Stretch="None"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                    </ListView>
```

Code Behind file

```
public void BindImgs()
        {
        //Some code here

            AClass a=new AClass();
            foreach (var photo in Photos)
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(photo.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute); 
                a.Srcimg.Add(uri);
            }
            lbxItems.DataContext =a;
        }

    public class AClass
        {
            private List<Uri> _srcimg = new List<Uri>();

            public List<Uri> Srcimg
            {
                get { return _srcimg; }
            }
        }
```

When I run the app it just shows the uri string path instead of showing the image. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Xaml to this and you should have more luck:-)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Srcimg}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image  Height="113" Source="{Binding}" Stretch="None"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```